# How should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, beta, favicon, design

> What should our logo and site design look like?
>
> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it.
>
> *<sub>6th question in [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)</sub>*

Ok, so here it goes. Please provide ideas to help make this site attractive.

Comment: cc @ManishEarth :)

Comment: Pretty soon to ask this. We need to wait till graduation or atleast public beta.

Comment: @AnkitSharma The blog post says - _"Every Beta"_. This as well is a beta, isn't it?

Comment: Its now a private beta and we going to get logo and specific look after graduation and its not going to come till few years.

Comment: @AnkitSharma _"Years"_? I don't think its true. The email invitation to the private beta said private betas last for a few weeks.

Comment: Its been more then 2 year and still Movies & TV beta is not graduated. Its confirmed for graduation soon but no official date came yet. So normally all beta site takes year in graduation.

Comment: @AwalGarg There is no harm in talking about site design right now, but Ankit Sharma is right - we don't get a site design until we graduate. Assuming this private beta goes fine, it will last a week or two before we move into _public_ beta, but the site will probably spend at least one year (perhaps more) in public beta before it graduates.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to post my idea for the logo of this website.. Now obviously am not a designer, but still I have designed a logo, which I feel will look really good for the website with a tinge of orange colors for links and question titles....

[image]

**Information for the logo**

Font : *Samarkan*

Colors : *Its a Gradient overlay, so I've `#ff7200` with a location of `28%` and the gradient ends with `#c10000` and yes, its vertically colored.*

[Download PSD + Font](http://decodingweb.com/collectibles/hinduism_logo.zip)

---

**Why this logo?**

- As we know, saffron and red is used by hindu as [kumkuma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumkuma) and also for puja, tilaks etc, so I chose those colors.
- Sanskrit is the primary liturgical language of Hinduism so these fonts does give a Sanskrit look
- And last but not the least, I don't want to use any specific symbol to represent hinduism as it may hurt the sentiments of some caste group and hence, to be neutral I chose this.

Comment: Awesome. Completely agree that logo should plainly echo what we want it to echo. Great answer :)

Comment: I looks more like a word then a logo. Logo should be a symbol. For more reference, please see other sites on SE. You'll get a better idea of what I am saying.

Comment: @DroidDev Its fine if you downvote as they are personal opinions, but I wouldn't recommend to use any religious symbol which may hurt the sentiments of other sub castes... As this is a religion related website, its good to be neutral instead of being too specific :) .. Also, its nothing like a logo should be a symbol, if you look at [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) that just looks similar to this with brackets showing the meaning

Comment: @Mr.Alien Is that your own creation? It looks pretty nice (though this would serve better as a site title than as a logo).

Comment: @senshin Yes I just designed that and I've provided the source files for download on my own server, feel free to modify and reshare, as am not very good at designs...

Comment: This is a good candidate for the site title, but the logo doesn't need to have any text in it...

Comment: Downvote on meta is a symbol for disagreement, that's why no reputation is associated on meta. I have also not upvoted any other answer on this post for the same reason that you describe here. Your creation is nice, but it doesn't look like a symbol and I was in disagreement that it should be used as a site logo. :)

Comment: @DroidDev Yea I am aware of that and hence I stated that opinions do differ :) and thanks for appreciating but I just posted an idea, we can sure work over this version and make a better one..

Comment: Actually I am not good with designing, but I'll surely look for some good logo and then ping you with a link so that you can do some gradient job on it and make it look like this one. :)

Comment: @DroidDev Sure, I'll look forward for that... :)

Comment: I would like to drop in thoughts. Certainly there is no requirement that the site's main logo "not contain text" or have some infographics and stuff. Plain text sometimes is the best choice. I would also like to say that flat designs for UX are trending these days. I would see if I can come up with something and add it as a version to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Alien http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/69/75 <-- see and comment and add and improve and critic and bla bla, please :) Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Consider using the same styles to design an Om logo because that is a universal representation of Hinduism - and globally known to refer Hindus in general.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest an Om symbol is a Saffron background:

[image]

or a variant of the ancient Hindu sparrow tailed flag:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest second one `ancient Hindu sparrow tailed flag`.

Answer (score 5):

I support @bytebuster's AUM!

[image: AUM]

Comment: I think saffron/red color or background would be more suitable

Answer (score 4):

Ganesha is a god which is followed fron north to south. And even he is to be called first in all Puja and karam kands. Then our logo should be tribute to lor ganesha. And Om is also a big part of Hiduism.

So our logo should be like this

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_BQmHxLnNHek/TI1WoazCgcI/AAAAAAAABBk/Oky7KEqk_Nc/s1600/hasc+logo+final.jpg]

[Image source](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_BQmHxLnNHek/TI1WoazCgcI/AAAAAAAABBk/Oky7KEqk_Nc/s1600/hasc+logo+final.jpg).

And site design should be with cream and orange colour. Logo should be orange. And badges should be like Swastika.

Comment: I support the idea and design of Om and Ganesha in the logo, but man that logo is ugly.

Comment: Swastika badges, brilliant idea! Also, what's the text underneath the logo?

Comment: @AdityaSomani HASC is site name. The logo is just to represent idea, as i am not a designer, so can't draw exact one.

Comment: HASC? What does that stand for?

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, we should avoid the usage of swastikas as a design element on this site because the symbol is today primarily associated with Naziism, its historical roots notwithstanding.

Comment: if someone like nazi uses "Om" as their symbol so according to you we should also stop using it in future. Swastika is a symbol of purity , it is integral to our religion and by not making it prominent we will be diluting the very foundation of this site. These symbols have special significance which goes beyond "looks" , they have tremendous energies,

Comment: @AdityaSomani don't know

Comment: @vedic agree with you. And swastik is one of our primary symbols. So it should be somewhere in our site.

Comment: @senshin Correlation not equal to causation. If tomorrow some other symbol becomes related to something bad, will be stop using it as well. It is our duty to promote the swastika as it one of our core holy symbols. And the anti-swastika is a different albeit very similar entity. We must preach that difference and break the correlation. We must create awareness about the religion and it's symbolisms. This is the very core of this website.

Comment: I agree that we should take this opportunity to take back the swastika for hinduism.

Comment: LOVE this one. Very very nice

Answer (score 1):

Considering the Logo.

Some obvious suggestions would be **Aum**, **Dharmachakra**, and **Asoka Chakra**.

There is a similar [discussion at Buddhism.SE](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/lets-choose-the-logo), and I suppose some clash may happen for two Betas as of what symbol will represent both Betas.

I have explained my thoughts there and I'm [suggesting](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32/4) to work in collaboration to figure out what symbols would serve each of the sites.

Comment: Using Ashok chakra will not be good idea. Reasons: Ashok was against some of Hindu traditions of that time and became buddhist. The other problem is Ashok kingdom related symbols are used by Indian Government. Let's not mix.

Answer (score 1):

1. [image]

   Used by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism), available in different size in `svg` and `png` format at [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Om_symbol.svg)

   License: [public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:public_domain)

---

2. [image]

---

<sup>For the clarification of your  votes on first or second, you can consider to vote on respective comments below as well.</sup>

Comment: +1 for the first

Comment: +1 fort the second

Answer (score 0):

I do not like a very bright orange colour because it appears too modern and unnatural.

I would prefer the more natural and a bit dull shade of **natural [Ochre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochre)** which was originally used in rituals, decorative and ornamental purpose.

Here are 2 suggested shade from [HTML Color picker tool](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/),

[image: Yellow Ochre]
Yellow Ochre

[image: Red Ochre]
Red Ochre

These 2 colour (or their gradations) should be used for the upper banner of the website and the inner text highlights, hyperlinks, etc.

Notably, [biology stackexchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) is using a very nice wallpaper throughout the webpage background. Now since Hinduism regards the festivity, we can use a pink, yellow and orange coloured wallpapers with respected symbols (except the Swastika, since it can be triggering for Western audience). You can use the auspicious symbols for Sun, Lotus, Namaskaram, sage sitting in a lotus posture, etc.

For Site Logo, I wholeheartedly support the [logo proposed by Ankit Sharma](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/27#27), except the blue margin looks bad, it can be made dark ochre red.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest Swastika and Om

Comment: A swastika is a terrible idea because it is primarily associated with Nazis nowadays.

Comment: Nazis appropriated our sacred symbols and misused it. Doesn't mean the original owners shouldn't use it.

Comment: @RBK Look, you have to think about this in terms of what is best for the site, not in terms of ideology. Yes, sure, it would be nice if we could plaster our site with swastikas and have everybody think good things about it, but that's just _not what would actually happen_.

Comment: @senshin Then it becomes all the more reason to use swastika, so that people all the world knows the truth. we are here to tell the world the truth and not hide behind the misrepresentation of our history/culture/religion.

Comment: @vedic There is a time and a place for any given battle to be fought. Perhaps the battle over the misrepresentation of the swastika is one to be fought, but this is not the place for it.

Comment: @senshin Battle! telling truth is **not** a battle and the very purpose of this site is to undo the wrong. My friend I understand your concern but that does not mean we stop using our holy symbols.

Comment: I agree with @senshin, if we want to tell the world about swasthika, the logo is not a proper place. It could fireback and do harm to the site.

Comment: @TejeshAlimilli It will generate curiosity. Not backfire. I'm nit saying let's use it in the logo, but that's only because I believe Om and Ganesha are better ideas and more important to our society. Nonetheless when people see something controversial so actively marketed, curiosity is generated. And that curiosity is what will help clear the confusion and misconception about the swastika.

Comment: When all is said and done, I'm pretty sure that the designers at Stack Exchange have the good sense not to use a swastika as a prominent design element on this site, so I'm not really interested in arguing this issue further.

Comment: as a matter of fact how about displaying swastika on our facebook, personal website, if possible on our corporate website, lets see how people react I am doing it today :D

Answer (score -1):

Ok, to add to @Mr. Alien's idea, here it goes:

[image: tis iz a custhum mate logo, okhey?]

This is for the site logo. We can ofcourse scale it down and do other things...

Comment: This is close but instead of just highlighting the letter h, we can highlight the word hindu, whats your opinion over this?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ok, I tried what you said, honestly, its looking like two separate words. I don't think thats what we want. I will post the pic if you want that though.

Comment: As I said I suck at graphics, I still feel we should stick with the colors and logo which I shared, but as we know, long time for all these stuff to be discussed ;)