# Change the blue to Ochre/ saffron

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Hinduism SE page (main site) is based on a blue colour. Please update it with ochre/ saffron  colour.

Comment: You might add that suggestion [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like). Unfortunately, we do not get a new design until the developers get to this site. It could be months...or years :(